# I'm getting contradictory answers, what should I do with my code?

Tags: c++, text, directx

I am making a RPG game in C++ and DirectX.

I store all the data for the game in .txt files and read/write it using `ifstream/ofstream. this has worked well for me so far when talking about creature stats and I have a hack together for creature names but this is becoming a problem.

I can store strings in the txt file and read them but I am having trouble using them. for single words I have a hack but now I am up to the story line where characters are talking to each other it is a real problem.

I asked on gamedevelopment.stackexchange how to put text on screen and was told to use D3Dtext but that only accepts C-style strings and I can only read C++ strings from the text file. This is such a big problem now that I am willing to go back and re-factor what need sit as no progress can be made until this is sorted.

So now I have a bunch of questions and I dont know which to ask first:

1. I want a way to draw the letters like graphics. I was told this is what D3Dtext does but I want to implement it my self if I can I just need info on how if someone knows?
2. If I am to use D3Dtext like so called experts advise I have to use C-style strings. so how can I convert C-style strings to C++ strings? I have a method now but that requires the new and delete operator for every string and I can see the being a big problem as it grows in complexity?
3. Is there a way to read C-style strings? Maybe a replacement for ifstream. I would like to keep the txt files as I really dont want to use xml but I could change the file format if it was a viable solution?
4. Premature optimisation I know but I plan to use the same function for every piece of text in the game so what would be a good way of doing this in terms of speed (why I dont want new/delete for every string)?

I am happy to provide any information that would be needed to help me, just ask.

Comment: std::string s;  const char* cstring = s.c_str();

Comment: @meagar can you make your comment an answer so i can accept it. it was the most helpful one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert freely between C-style strings and C++'s `std::string`. Just use `my_cpp_string.c_str()` to get the C-string representation of a C++ string, and `std::string my_cpp_string(my_c_string)` to initialize a new std::string from a C-style string.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::string mystr = "Hello World.";
mystr.c_str(); // gets a null terminated const char* C-style string
```

Read your file as you are currently doing then if you need to access the c strings as above.

Comment: Non issue? C++ has always had a way to get a C style string out of a std::string :) Voted parent up.

Answer (score 1):

2) Use the `c_str()` method to pass your C++ strings to D3Dtext

```
some_D3Dtext_function(some_text.c_str())
```

3 and 4 then become non-issues.